# Creative solution for caching of list pages

Tags: caching

I have typical "list" pages on my site, for example to show a list of 20 photos with a pager to go to 2, 3, ... "next" and "last". The Urls for the pages are photos?page= ...

Then newest photos are shown on the first page. When I use caching it will cache all the list pages. The problem is that when one or more photos are added the cache has to be rebuild not just for the first page but also for all the other pages.

Is there a solution to this problem that wouldn't require constant rebuilding of all cached list pages?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Page-level caching has to be reset whenever a page's contents change.

You could, however, cache just *parts* of the page, and draw upon those caches to build the final page. You could also only lazily bust the cache, and only rebuild pages when they're actually viewed.